# How to use type constrains with Exists

Tags: purescript

```
data Foo a = Foo a
```

I can create an array of `Exists` https://github.com/purescript/purescript-exists

```
[(mkExists (Foo 0)), (mkExists (Foo "x"))]
```

How can I use type classes? I want to get `["0", "x"]`

```
getStrings :: Array (Exists Foo) -> Array String
getStrings list = map (runExists get) list
  where
  get :: forall a. Show a => Foo a -> String
  get (Foo a) = show a
```

> No type class instance was found for
>
> ```
> Prelude.Show _0
> ```
>
> The instance head contains unknown type variables. Consider adding a
>   type annotation.

Comment: Include definition of `Exists` and `mkExists` please.

Comment: https://github.com/purescript/purescript-exists/blob/master/src/Data/Exists.purs

Comment: this example by @natefaubion might help https://gist.github.com/natefaubion/d33aa875fa5c98178df159091fd4f348

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to bundle up the `show` function in your definition of `Foo`, something like this:

```
import Prelude
import Data.Exists

data Foo a = Foo a (a -> String)

type FooE = Exists Foo

mkFooE :: forall a. (Show a) => a -> FooE
mkFooE a = mkExists (Foo a show)

getStrings :: Array FooE -> Array String
getStrings = map (runExists get)
  where
  get :: forall a. Foo a -> String
  get (Foo a toString) = toString a

--

items :: Array FooE
items = [mkFooE 0, mkFooE 0.5, mkFooE "test"]

items' :: Array String
items' = getStrings items
```

Comment: What are the other options?

Comment: See [Phil's comment on the other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35990022/how-can-i-create-an-array-with-polymorphic-data#comment59645787_35991626) - it roughly ends up as the same thing. Since there is no evidence that the existential `a` can be `show`n it means you need to provide that evidence somehow along with the value.

Comment: Why cannot the evidence be provided like this `data Foo a = Foo (Show a) => a
`?

Comment: That's a whole other can of worms, but the short answer is "because the type system doesn't support it", I'm afraid. Phil would probably have to give the detailed explanation too, if you really want it ;)

Comment: It's not possible right now. If you wrote this in Haskell's GADT notation, it'd be `data Foo where Foo :: (Show a) => a -> Foo`. What you wrote is equivalent to `data Foo where Foo :: ((Show a) => a) -> Foo`, which is not the same. Really you want to pair a dictionary with a value, which might be written as `data Foo =  Foo (Show a *> a)`. Supporting types like that is a possibility, but we would have to decide what the correct typing rules would be. This is a good discussion to have on the GitHub issue.